# Invoking Entity Methods with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql, jpql

I have looked around in SO but haven't found an answer for my specific question.

Is there any way to tell Hibernate to invoke an entity method when executing a query?

For example:

```
SELECT o.getDescription() from Order o WHERE o.id = :id
```

And the `getDescription()` implementation being something like this:

```
public String getDescription(){
    return getFormattedOrderTime() + " " + getOrderDetails().getDescription();
}
```

I know in this example such a thing wouldn't be necessary. I created this example just to illustrate what I want.

I would just like to know if that invocation in the query is at all possible, so I can avoid a huge workaround that I'll have to do.

PS: It doesn't matter if the solution is Hibernate Specific.

**Additional Info:** Hibernate Version: 3.6.10.Final

Comment: Are you using JPA with Hibernate implementation or plain Hibernate?

Comment: I'm using JPA with Hibernate implementation, but I'm opened to a solution with either if you have one. I have no problem with using vendor specific solutions in this project.

Comment: Well, assuming `formattedOrderTime` and `orderDetails` are mapped attributes of your entity, you should get those instead and then call your `order.getDescription()`.

Comment: Yes, that was my first idea. I don't imagine there's anyway around it, huh? Anyway, I'll leave the question here in case someone has an alternative. Thanks Luiggi

Answer (score 0):

You should aadd a @PostLoad method in your @Entity

```
@PostLoad
public String getDescriptionWithDetails(){
   return getFormattedOrderTime() + " " + getOrderDetails().getDescription();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but does this work in query execution time, because the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html) leads me on another direction.

Comment: the @PostLoad method getDescriptionWithDetails() will be called every time your Order entity is loaded (ie. select from Order...)